# (C) Can't read string array values between functions

Tags: c

I have one char strings pointers array, lets call it "str_array".
I also have 3 strings:
1."Hello"
2."World"
3."Today"
(Every string ends with \0)
And I have this function, that receives our str_array, the size of it, and another pointers arr that is not releveant for my question.
The problem that I encounter, is that function "scanString" receives NULL, or garbage values, instead of the strings inside str_array.

```
    unsigned int  RemoveFromStrArray(char*** str_array, unsigned  int  str_array_size, char** ptr_to_chars_array)
    {
int k = 0;
        while (k != str_array_size)
        {
            // This is the part where im trying to scan str_array strings.
            scanString(*str_array[k]);
            str_array++;
            k++;
        }
    }



    int scanString(char* string)
    {
        int c = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while (string[c] != '\0')
        {
            if (string[c] == 1)
            {
                moveOneBack(string, c);
                c--;
                counter++;
            }
            c++;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

I've been trying multiple alternative ways to scan str_array string arrays.
But all of my times I just had to deal with garbage values or NULL strings.
How do I reach str_array strings, that would be passed by reference to scanString?

Picture of what I'm talking about:
[image: picture of what I'm talking about]

BIG THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: `str_array` is a `char***` (triple star!), meaning a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a char. You're passing `&str_array` (a pointer to `str_array` - quadruple star!!!) to `scanString`, which expects a `char*`. Do you see the problem? Your compiler should be telling you about this.

Comment: The code here doesn't compile (`error: 'k' undeclared`). Please try to create a [mre]. Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your comment. I've been trying multiple other choices, like scanString(**str_array), or using int i, *str_array[i], but then I encounter a problem that I can only get the first string, for our example, "Hello". Next run, the array becomes NULL and won't even get inside the 2nd function.

Comment: @trentcl I'll edit my post, however, the only problem I have to get fixed is how I'm getting all the str_array values, rather than just the first.

Comment: How are you calling `RemoveFromStrArray`? I would only expect it to take a `char**` not a `char***`.

Comment: @ZvikaCohen When you're first getting the hang of using pointers like this, it really really *really* helps to draw a picture. Get a really big piece of paper, or a white board, and just make a diagram of the memory `str_array` uses, variables, etc. The more you do that, the faster you'll get to a point where a) you don't need the paper, and b) you make a lot fewer mistakes.

Comment: @Kevin In the main program, there is a decleration of char** str_array, and the way the function being used is: res = RemoveFromStrArray(&str_array, str_array_size, ptr_to_chars_array);   Unfortunately, can't change any of the prototypes, since that's the way we need to send it to the course teacher.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you for your advice. I've been trying to do that, I'll add a picture right now. Unfortunately, My mind is being blown when I'm trying to understand how to write the code. So confusing, and little time to send the task.

Comment: Fixing the post isn't primarily to help **you**, it's to help **us** -- the cadre of Internet strangers whose assistance you are asking for. Personally, I might spend thirty seconds trying to get code to compile before I give up and move on to the next question. The code still doesn't link, by the way -- ``undefined reference to `moveOneBack'``.

Comment: @tentcl I don't want to waste anyone's time, the only question I can't answer myself is how do I get str_array strings, to get sent by reference to another function?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] so that prospective answerers can reproduce and understand the problem.

Comment: It depends how the strings were allocated; a minimal example is probably important.

Answer (score 0):

> `unsigned int  RemoveFromStrArray(char*** str_array`

You've got at least one too many indirections there. From your drawing, `str_array` refers to an array, so it's effectively a pointer, and the values in the array are pointers to `char`. You don't seem to be changing the array itself, e.g. you're not making `str_array` refer to some *other* array of strings, so there's no need to pass the address of the array. So `char **` is closer to the type you want.

> `str_array++;`

I'm not sure why you're incrementing `str_array` *and* using `k` as an index into the array. Although it's safe to modify parameters locally like that, it's nice to avoid it so that you can refer to them while debugging. Consider this:

```
unsigned int RemoveFromStrArray(char** str_array, 
                                unsigned  int  str_array_size)
{
    int k = 0;
    while (k != str_array_size)
    {
        char *string = str_array[k];
        scanString(string);
        k++;
    }
}
```

That is, the values in `str_array` are of type `char *`, so `str_array[k]` has that type. Copying it into a temporary variable `string` makes it a little easier to see what's going on. (I removed the last parameter, `ptr_to_chars_array`, to keep things simple and because it's not used. You'll add it back if you have plans for it, I'm sure.)

A `for` loop would be a little more compact but otherwise equivalent:

```
unsigned int RemoveFromStrArray(char** str_array, 
                                unsigned  int  str_array_size)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < str_array_size; k++)
    {
        char *string = str_array[k];
        scanString(string);
    }
}
```